# Change word macro to scan selected text only (to save time in large documents)

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight, selectedtext

I used the macro below and it works nicely! However, would it be possible to limit it to the text I selected in the active document only? The seperate document has 2000 words, so if the active document has too much text it will take ages... Even though I might only want to scan like 100 words to be highlighted... If anyone can help, much appreciated!

```
Sub B2_Highlighter_Selection_andAllWordForms()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    Dim FRDoc As Document, FRList, i As Long
    Set FRDoc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\Milan van Bree\Google Drive\Heerbeeck College\3. Extra materiaal algemeen\Macros for Word\B2words.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Addtorecentfiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    FRList = FRDoc.Range.Text: FRDoc.Close False: Set FRDoc = Nothing
    With Selection.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        'Process each word from the List
        For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FRList, vbCr)) - 1
            .Text = Split(FRList, vbCr)(i)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried to google it and I did find some answers, but that didnt compute with my specific macro type that highlights words that are stored in a seperate document.

Comment: ` With Selection.Range.Find` doesn't already do what you want?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/47195-macro-find-highlight-words-list.html#post173770. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 2):

After:

```
.Replacement.Highlight = True
```

Insert:

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

Comment: Thanks for rosponding so quickly! If you don't mind I would like to ask one more thing about this though. Because I just tested this macro as follows: first I had 1 word-file with only one paragraph of text in it, then I selected it and ran the macro. Then I went to another document that has a lot of text in it, but I still selected the exact same text as before.

For some reason, the second run took waaaay longer, which gives me the feeling that it is still also scanning al the other text. Could that be? And if so, would you know how to fix that?